# How to split the Date() in JavaScript and remove the last GMT+0530 (IST)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want output like below **Wed May 17 2017 15:13:02** without  GMT+0530 (IST.  Below is my code , I am trying to split but Not getting the output.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
var d = new Date();
```

var res = d.split("",5);
document.getElementById("dateshow").innerHTML = res;

Comment: So you want change the `toString` function?

Comment: I want output only [Wed May 17 2017 15:13:02]

Comment: var dateAndTime = d.toDateString() + d.toLocaleTimeString()

Comment: @MG83 Thanks so much, that is what i was in need; var dateAndTime = d.toDateString() + '  ' + d.toLocaleTimeString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this
Convert the date to string to get each word. Then take the required words and join then to get the required string

```js
var d = new Date().toString();
var l = d.split(' ').splice(0, 5).join(' ')
console.log(l)
```

Comment: Thanks @brk, It is working perfectly.